# How to download image file with given name in safari in javascript

Tags: javascript, safari, html5-canvas, imagedownload

If there is a any image rendered in brower. I have given a link to download that image with customized name. But in safari file is downloaded with unknown name.
In other browser it works fine.

What I got. In safari download attribute of link does not support. Becuase of that all files is getting downloaded with unknown file name In that how can i give a name to downloaded file.

/* I have tried this code.*/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body onload="myFunct">
    <canvas id="cnv" width="32" height="32"></canvas>
    <a id="dl" download="Canvas.png" href="#" onClick="dlCanvas">Download Canvas</a>


    <script>
        function myFunct() {
            var canvas = document.getElementById("cnv");
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

            /* FILL CANVAS WITH IMAGE DATA */
            function r(ctx, x, y, w, h, c) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.rect(x, y, w, h);
                ctx.strokeStyle = c;
                ctx.stroke();
            }
            r(ctx, 0, 0, 32, 32, "black");
            r(ctx, 4, 4, 16, 16, "red");
            r(ctx, 8, 8, 16, 16, "green");
            r(ctx, 12, 12, 16, 16, "blue");
            document.getElementById("dl").addEventListener('click', dlCanvas, false);
        }

        /* REGISTER DOWNLOAD HANDLER */
        /* Only convert the canvas to Data URL when the user clicks. 
           This saves RAM and CPU ressources in case this feature is not required. */
        function dlCanvas() {
            var dt = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
            /* Change MIME type to trick the browser to downlaod the file instead of displaying it */
            dt = dt.replace(/^data:image\/[^;]*/, 'data:application/octet-stream');

            /* In addition to <a>'s "download" attribute, you can define HTTP-style headers */
            dt = dt.replace(/^data:application\/octet-stream/, 'data:application/octet-stream;headers=Content-Disposition%3A%20attachment%3B%20filename=Canvas.png');

            this.href = dt;
        };
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you share your HTML code?

Comment: I have edited a post and shared a code.